# How do I configure DOCFX to show source code on each page

Tags: docfx

Would like to include a view into the source code for each page, but don't know what option to change in docfx.json to do it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, see the [DocFx documentation on `_gitUrlPattern`](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#322-reserved-metadata).

In **docfx.json** you might need to add something like:

```
        "globalMetadata": {
            "_gitUrlPattern": "vso"
```

Comment: Just curious, that appears to set a known property _gitUrlPattern. But the value is vso.  Not sure what that does.

Comment: If I understand you right, DocFx only supports this feature for repos in either GitHub ("github") and Visual Studio Online/Azure DevOps Online ("vso").